# Setup Apache Password Protection

Tags: apache-2.2, password-protected

I have some difficulties setting up password protection in Apache

In .htaccess, I have

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Test Server"
AuthType Basic

require user testuser
```

Then in .htpasswd, I have something like

```
testuser:encrypted password
```

The problem now is I forgot what .htpasswd generator I used. When I try to add a new user and password, it doesn't work. eg. when I put `require user newuser` it fails always (prompt keeps reappearing). Then when I revert to `testuser` it works

How can I setup such that I have 1 or some "admins" that can access everything and viewers that can view only specific folders ... eg

```
/               - only admins
    /folder1    - only admins or folder1's users
    /folder2    - only admins or folder2's users
```

Also what do I do to not allow showing of directory listing

Answer (score 4):

The `require user` directive only allows for one user to access the particular resource. To allow multiple users you should configure an [AuthGroupFile](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_auth.html#authgroupfile) and use the `Require group` directive to allow access to the resource. The apache documentation is [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html)

/folder1/.htaccess

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/.GroupFile
AuthName "Test Group1"
AuthType Basic

require group Group1
```

/folder2/.htaccess

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/.GroupFile
AuthName "Test Group2"
AuthType Basic

require group Group2
```

etc.

If you want to specify multiple groups then

```
require group Group1 Group2 ...
```

and in the GroupFile

```
Group1: testuser admin1 admin2
Group2: testuser1 admin1 admin2
```

Comment: What do you use to generate passwords?

Comment: in your example above `htpasswd /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/.htpasswd UserName` would do it.

Comment: I think theres various methods of encryption? also theres different string length apparently? like from http://aspirine.org/htpasswd_en.html

Comment: @jiewmeng: Yes you can specify htpasswd -m for MD5 -d for crypt -s for SHA have a look at the [**htpasswd**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/htpasswd) man page

Comment: thanks, I can also use crypt from http://aspirine.org/htpasswd_en.html

Comment: oh and how can I specify multiple groups to allow? eg. Can I do AdminGrp: admin1 admin2 | Grp1: user1 user2 then do something like `require group AdminGrp Grp1`?

Comment: Also whats a way to debug whats wrong?

Comment: Your have answered your own question regarding multiple groups `require group AdminGrp Grp1` is correct. Regarding debugging have a look in you apache error log.

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess in root:

```
AuthUserFile /var/.htpasswd
AuthName "Test Server"
AuthType Basic
require user admin
Options -Indexes
```

.htaccess in folder1:

```
AuthUserFile /var/.htpasswd
AuthName "Test Server"
AuthType Basic
require user admin folder1
```

.htaccess in folder2:

```
AuthUserFile /var/.htpasswd
AuthName "Test Server"
AuthType Basic
require user admin folder2
```

Comment: What do you use to generate passwords?

Comment: @jiewmeng htpasswd

Comment: I think theres various methods of encryption? also theres different string length apparently? like from http://aspirine.org/htpasswd_en.html

Comment: thanks, I can also use crypt from http://aspirine.org/htpasswd_en.html